# Line-height causing uneven divs

Tags: html, css

I would like two divs to sit beside each other and aligned at the bottom. I have a button and when I set line-height on it drops slightly. I'll show an example with images.

What I desire:

[image]

What is happening:

[image]

The following codepen shows the drop:

http://codepen.io/basickarl/pen/KVXqxR?editors=110

html:

```
<div class="div1">
  hello<br>
  hello<br>
  hello<br>
  hello<br>
  hello<br>
  hello<br>
</div>
<div class="div2">
  <button class="butt">push meh</button>
</div>
```

css:

```
.div1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}
.div2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: lime;
}
.butt {
  line-height: 40px;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

I understand that the text in the button is aligned and that line-height creates a kind of bubble around it. Any ways to get them aligned anyhow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:bottom` to `.div2` (and/or `.div1`):

```
.div2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: lime;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

**[codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrZOLM?editors=110)**

The default vertical alignment for inline elements is baseline, which is what you're seeing.

Comment: I am simply amazed at the things I learn on this website, good day to you Sir! :)